# Get "send as" or "on behalf of" information from Exchange server

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mapi

As we know, there is a permission you can grant on the Exchange server that allows a user (foo) to send email in the name of as the permission granter (bar).

- On behalf of -> From: foo@baz.qux on behalf of bar@baz.qux
- Send as      -> From: bar@baz.qux

How the from field appears in the recipient’s email is controlled by the Exchange - as soon as the mail passes the Exchange the corresponding fields are set.

- Send as      -> "from: bar@baz.qux".
- On behalf of -> "from: bar@baz.qux" and "sender: foo@baz.qux".

Now it comes to my question:
Is there a way to get the Exchange rule which controls the appearance for the recipient? For example, via the MAPI interface or Exchange Web Service?

Comment: "appearance" in what sense? SMTP address vs display name?

Comment: I am talking about the SMTP address. Because the sender’s name will not always be set and has no effect to the mail routing, right? The request result should give me information like that: foo@bar.qux has send as permission for bar@bar.qux or foo@bar.qux has send on behalf permission for bar@bar.qux - at the end I only want to be able to distinguish between those two options.

Answer (score 0):

When Outlook sends on behalf of a user, about half dozen `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz` MAPI properties are set, email address and name are always included - you can see these properties in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button.

When you use `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property in OOM, you can only set the name (which can be a problem if the name is ambiguous). But when the message goes out, name name will be resolved, the `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz` MAPI properties will be set.